# SQL Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Schedule_OverdueTasks 
WHERE Job_No LIKE (
    SELECT DISTINCT AREA_ID 
    FROM V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES 
    WHERE AREA_DESC IN ('aaa', 'bbb') + '%'
```

but this gives me this error:

`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

When I run my query like so, I get no errors, because there is only 1 `AREA_I`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Schedule_OverdueTasks 
WHERE Job_No LIKE (
    SELECT DISTINCT AREA_ID 
    FROM V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES 
    WHERE AREA_DESC = 'aaa') + '%'
```

I have tried redoing my query like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Schedule_OverdueTasks 
INNER JOIN V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES 
    ON V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.JOB_NUMBER = Schedule_OverdueTasks.Job_No 
WHERE V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.AREA_DESC IN ('aaa', 'bbb')
```

But I do not get the same number of results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you use `exists`:

```
SELECT ot.*
FROM Schedule_OverdueTasks ot
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES pd
              WHERE ot.Job_No LIKE pd.area_id + '%' AND
                    AREA_DESC IN ('aaa', 'bbb')
             );
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment so I need to use the answer section, but `like` takes a `scalar` `data type` not a `table valued data type

Meaning you can only compare it to 1 value

so without knowing your data structure the best I would be able to recommend at the moment is

```
    SELECT *
FROM Schedule_OverdueTasks
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT AREA_ID
    FROM V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES
    WHERE AREA_DESC = 'aaa'
    ) vcpd ON Job_No LIKE Area_ID + '%'
```

Edit: 
As Per Gordons answer an exist would be ideal for performance while not changing the result set though the optimizer might interpret this as an exist but better to write what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query, it looks like Job_No has additional characters on the end of it and AREA_ID would be the first few characters of Job_No.  If AREA_ID is a set length (say 5 characters), you could try this

```
SELECT * FROM Schedule_OverdueTasks 
INNER JOIN V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES ON LEFT(Schedule_OverdueTasks.Job_No, 5) = V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.AREA_ID 
WHERE V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.AREA_DESC IN ('aaa', 'bbb')
```

Answer (score 0):

the resultset inside the LIKE operator must return one and only one record since the LIKE operator will be evaluated to return true or false.

Use TOP 1 to avoid the error.

This query will not fail, but as to getting the right results, that is a different matter. You must revise your data and conditions.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Schedule_OverdueTasks 
WHERE Job_No LIKE (SELECT TOP 1 AREA_ID 
                   FROM V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES 
                   WHERE AREA_DESC IN ('aaa', 'bbb') + '%'
```

To test the behavior of LIKE run the following query and the same error message will be produced.

```
SELECT  foo
FROM    ( SELECT    1 foo
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    1 foo
        ) bar
WHERE   1 LIKE ( SELECT 1 foo
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 2 foo
               );
```

Comment: Why the down-vote? This addresses exactly the error message and the subject title of this question. whatever...